# Trashing on maxProcessCount?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dex

Can someone please share dexOptions with MultiDex for very large multi-module apps?

We have been using the typical 4g heap with associated gradle.properties settings but  performance of transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug has started to tail off and I believe the cause is thrashing.  A clean build sometimes hangs for 10 minutes or more on this task.  We are using gradle 4.3 and Android Plugin 3.0.1.

Do you use the same settings for all library modules or do you use different settings in the largest Application one?

The only reference to thrashing I see is here. [DexOptions documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html) contains this info:

> Integer maxProcessCount
>   The maximum number of concurrent processes that can be used to dex. Defaults to 4.
>
> Be aware that the number of concurrent process times the memory requirement  represent the minimum amount of memory that will be used by the dx processes:
>
> `Total Memory = maxProcessCount * javaMaxHeapSize`
>
> To avoid thrashing, keep these two settings appropriate for your configuration.